# Weird ripple issue on first layer

Tags: creality-ender-3

Not quite sure whats going on here, seems to happen at most temperatures and changing Z offset height doesn't change anything until it starts to cause stringing.

[image: Image of my first layer with the issue]

Comment: Hello Ollie7890. Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.